# What is the homotopy type of $S^2 - p - q\ $?

Tags: algebraic-topology

Let $p,q$ be two distinct points of $S^2.$ Then what would be the homotopy type of $S^2 - p - q\ $?

If we join $p,q$ by two $1$-cells, one cell (say $A$) lying entirely on $S^2$ and one (say $B$) lying outside $S^2$ then both the cells are contractible and $S^2$ along with those two cells gives us a CW complex structure in which both the cells are included as subcomplexes. Let $X$ be that CW complex. Then $X / A \simeq X \simeq X/B.$ But $X/A \approx S^2/\{p,q\}$ and $X/B \approx S^2 \vee S^1.$ So we have $S^2/\{p,q\} \simeq S^2 \vee S^1.$

Here instead of making that construction if we say that $S^2 - p \approx \mathbb R^2$ then the point $q$ is mapped homeomorphically to a point of $\mathbb R^2.$ By translating the point suitably we can think of that the point is the origin. Then doesn't deleting the points $p$ and $q$ from $S^2$ amount to deleting the origin from $\mathbb R^2\ $?

Any help in this regard would be much appreciated. Thanks for your time.

Comment: Note that quotient is not setminus.

Comment: Oh! Sorry. I misinterpret the thing. Many many thanks for pointing that out @user10354138.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hint: If $p$, $q$ are the North and South poles, then the equator $S^1$ is a deformation retract of $S^2 \backslash\{p,q\}$.

Comment: Yeah the second case gives me exactly that since $\mathbb R^2 \setminus \{(0,0)\}$ deformation retracts to the unit circle. But what's going wrong in my first attempt? It is clear that $S^2 \vee S^1 \not\simeq S^1.$